# Не могу никак подключить картинку, путь: папка biologiya, папка images, и сама картинка 1.jpg

Tags: html

есть пример код:

```html
<img src=“biologiya/images/1.jpg”>
```

Помогите пожалуйста, путь к картинке правильный и название все правильные но картинка не показываться

Comment: Если директория `biologiya` в корне, то `<img src="/biologiya/images/1.jpg" alt="">`

Answer (score -1):

самый оптимальный вариант без слеша перед biologiya

```html
<img src="...biologiya/images/1.jpg" alt="">
```

либо с помощью три точки в начале, когда ставите / вы закрепляете ссылку за корнем сайта, если сайт открыть с другой папки или устройства, путь сломается

или попробуйте скопировать относительный путь в вашем редакторе кода (правой кнопкой мыши нажимаете на картинку и выбираете Copy Relative Path и вставляете)

Comment: <img src="biologiya/images/1.jpg" alt="">

Comment: Что значит синтаксис "три точки в начале"?  Где об этом почитать в документации?

Comment: значит что папка находится где-то в другой папке но мы сокращаем и не указываем все остальное